# Why did Skeletor act out of character?

Tags: he-man

Watching this

made me wonder whether there was a reason why Skeletor saved the children in the special? Was he really bad?

Helping would imply that he has a sense of ethics, but if so then why did he do all those rampages to control Greyskull?

Comment: For fun? I am not quite sure what you mean....

Comment: then whats the meaning of battling over and over to He-man? I understand that was trying to get the Greyskull castle, but this make skeletor bad per se?

Comment: OK, but could you clarify what you mean by "for fun"?

Comment: You are right I didnt say the question well.

Comment: I made some edits to clarify your question. Feel free to roll back the edits if they conflict with your intent.

Comment: Does Skeletor ever commit any evil acts other than attempts to acquire power?  It's real easy to call that "evil" when your dad is already king.

Comment: @tbrookside - Worth asking as a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to *[He-Man and She-Ra: A Complete Guide to the Classic Animated Adventures](https://he-man.fandom.com/wiki/He-Man_and_She-Ra:_A_complete_Guide_to_the_Classic_Animated_Adventures)*, Skeletor<sub><sup><sup><sup>TM</sup></sup></sup></sub> simply felt compassion toward the children, motivated by the Spirit of Christmas<sub><sup><sup><sup>TM</sup></sup></sup></sub> that has permeated Eternia<sub><sup><sup><sup>TM</sup></sup></sup></sub>.

> Determined not to stay in one place, Skeletor orders the children to
> walk through the snowy tundra. However, the children are cold and
> weak, and the Manchines' puppy, Relay, cannot move through the thick
> snow. **Skeletor, feeling a tinge of compassion, gives the children
> coats and carries Relay himself.** The children tell Skeletor about
> Christmas, but he does not seem to understand the concept. He-Man and
> She-Ra arrive to save the children just as Hordak and an army of Horde
> Troopers appear on the scene. Hordak deflects one of Skeletor's blasts
> back at the Lord of Destruction, and the villain is knocked to the
> ground. Horde Prime arrives and prepares to take the children. **A
> confused Skeletor, motivated by the spirit of Christmas, saves the
> children. He-Man and She-Ra throw Horde Prime's ship back to Horde
> World. A perplexed Skeletor is reassured by She-Ra that Christmas only
> comes once a year.**

Comment: Confused? He didn't look at all (at least when he finds the childrens and blast the ice beast), and as @tbrookside says, I wouldn't say he is pure evil, he is more like a rascal. Thanks for taking your time and provide a certainly valuable answer.